# Dealing with a empty item in an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node-red

Im using node red to put something together simply, I'm not really a js person so I'm struggling a bit.

I have to create this json payload. If for example VpidA : msg.payload.ChanStat.VpidA[0] is empty or undefined, is there a way i can put a default value in? I need to do this for potentially many more items and I think catch statement might be required? Although seems like it might get messy...thoughts?

```html
msg.payload = [{
    
    measurement: "a box",
        fields: {
            Sync: parseInt(syncStatus),
            cCRC: parseInt(msg.payload.ChanStat.cCRC[0]),
            yCRC: parseInt(msg.payload.ChanStat.yCRC[0]),
            lineRate: msg.payload.ChanStat.LineRate[0],
            VpidA : msg.payload.ChanStat.VpidA[0]


        },
        tags:{
            host:"a box",
            input: msg.payload.ChanStat.ChanNum[0],
            type: "sdi"
        },
        timestamp: new Date()
}];
return msg;
```

i

Comment: `msg.payload.ChanStat.VpidA[0] || defaultVpidA`

Comment: Why does `undefined` as a value bother you? What would you want a "default" value to be in the of that array element not having a value?

Comment: I hate it when the data is no consistent... if an array is expected and that array can be empty, then return an empty array. I have even seen worse implementations where a property was returned as an array of objects if there were more than 1 index, and as an object (the only one) if there was only 1 index... no better way to mess up

Comment: Thanks chaps, actually the problem in how nodered passes the message in from the XML to JSON parser from the previous... I need to trap a error on the property not actually being there in the first place .. if you see what I mean?

Comment: @Barmar better use msg.payload.ChanStat.VpidA[0] ?? defaultVpidA in case the value is 0.

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator?

Answer (score 1):

You can test for the presence of variable with a simple if statement (assuming you are in a Function Node)

```
if (msg.payload.ChanStat.VpidA[0] == undefined){
   //do what ever needs doing if the property doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Thanks this more like it I think, is there a way I can do it inline in the json payload?